# HttpWebRequest passing Authentication Bearer token on redirect

Tags: c#, http, oauth-2.0

When doing HTTP requests I specify the OAuth2 token in my code in the following way:

```
WebClient webClient = ...;
webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");
```

But when `uri` is redirect one, then following request failured, because `Authorization` header is stipped on redirect:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)webClient.GetWebRequest(uri); // public method in derived class
```

It is possible to disable `AllowAutoRedirect` and set it to `false`, and then manually handle redirects.

Is it a simpler way to handle redirects avoiding manual handling, and preserve access token?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set [AllowAutoRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect?view=net-6.0) to False, and read the l[ocation redirect from the headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) and make subsequent requests.

They key is to catch the redirect response starting with 3xx and then parse the location header.

If you want to follow the redirect take a look at this SO issue.
[issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491525/httpclient-not-sending-basic-authentication-after-redirect/19493338#19493338)

Comment: This is exactly how I handle this, but I am looking for the simpler way. .NET already redirect automatically, I just want to ask it not to strip the Authorization header.

Comment: I've updated the answer, there's someone who had a similar question, but since you already implemented the manual solution you could just make it an extension method for the httpclient/webclient