# Xamarin Forms - Preserve Basic Authentication after redirect?

Tags: c#, heroku, xamarin.forms, httpclient, basic-authentication

How to preserve Basic Auth after redirecting in HttpClient?

- **Original URL:** https://myapp.herokuapp.com/api/login
- **Redirect URL with custom domain:** http://io.myapp.co/api/login

Below is my code I use in Xamarin Forms.
When I use the original URL, authentication works. But when I use the redirect URL, I get an **"Unauthorized"** response. The redirect URL works fine in **Postman**.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("email", TxtEmail.Text);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("password", TxtPassword.Text);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = HttpClientHelper.NdAuth;
    var result = await client.GetAsync(Constants.UrlLoginUser);
}
```

How to preserve Basic Auth while redirecting? How Postman is able to do it?

Comment: Take a look on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient it should give you an idea.

Comment: @EvZ I'm using the correct way to set authorization. What I want to find is, why the authentication gets destroyed when re-directing?

Comment: Same question have been asked already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14056998/1970317

Comment: Yes. But it's different in Xamarin forms. Credential cache is not available.